# Creating chat box with comet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, ajax

I'm writing a chat application.  I would like to know if there are problems in this code.

This function sends message:

```
function sendMessage()
{
    var text = $('#messageBox').val();
    $('#messageBox').val('');
    if($('.context').scrollTop() + $('.context').innerHeight() >= $('.context')[0].scrollHeight)
    {
        $(".context").animate({ scrollTop: $('.context')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    }
    $('.context').append('<div class="inner">'+ text +'</div>');
    if(text != '')
    {
        $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/chat/display',
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            data: 'text=' + text,
            cache: false,
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg == 1)
                {     
                    $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert('app has an error!');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the user sends a message, the message is written on the page before saving.

This code comes before the AJAX call.  Is it right?

```
$('.context').append('<div class="inner">'+ text +'</div>');
```

This function shows messages:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(displayMessage(lastTimestamp));
});

function displayMessage(time)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/chat/display',
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: 'time=' + time,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            if(msg)
            {
                if($('.context').scrollTop() + $('.context').innerHeight() >= $('.context')[0].scrollHeight)
                {
                    $(".context").animate({ scrollTop: $('.context')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
                }
                $('.context').append(msg[0]);
                time = msg[1];
            }
            setTimeout(displayMessage, 2000, time);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            displayMessage(time);
        }
    });
}
```

After the page loads, this function will be run to send data to be displayed.

Display method:

```
public function display()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['text']))
        {
            $text = DB::Escape($_POST['text']);
            $time = time();
            DB::Query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`user_id`, `to_message_id`, `text`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['id']}', '1', '{$text}', '{$time}')");
            if(DB::AffectedRows() > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return DB::LastError();
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['time']))
        {
            $time = intval($_POST['time']);
            $current = time();
            while (time() - $current < 10)
            {
                $result = self::findAll("WHERE (`timestamp` > '{$time}' AND `user_id` != '{$_SESSION['id']}')");
                if(count($result) > 0)
                {
                    $html = '';
                    foreach ($result as $obj)
                    {
                        $html .= '<div class="inner">'. $obj->text .'</div>';
                    }
                    return json_encode(array($html, $obj->timestamp));
                }
                else
                {
                    sleep(3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note this section:

```
while (time() - $current < 10)
```

This code slows sending and receiving messages so it takes several seconds to send and insert a message when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the sending button.

I'm using last timestamp for selecting messages from database. Is there a problem as the same time in timestamp column? I'd like to fix this apparent performance problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This code comes before the AJAX call. Is it right?

I would suggest adding the message to the DOM via the success callback - that way, if an error occurs then the message isn't displayed on the page.

## Other feedback

### Javascript

#### Cache DOM lookups

I would suggest you cache DOM references - e.g. store `$('#messageBox')`, `$('#send')`, `$('.context')` in variables (or better yet, [constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) if you are using [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)), preferably in a DOM-ready callback, because DOM-lookups aren't exactly cheap....

#### Accessing elements by class name can return multiple

Also: `$('.context')` is equivalent to `document.getElementsByClassName()`... which returns multiple elements. While methods like [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [`.innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) operate for the first matched element, it would be more appropriate to select an element by id (i.e. with [an id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)).

#### `$(document).ready()` with nested `$(window).load()`

I don't believe it is necessary to add the window load callback within the DOM ready callback. Also, bearing in mind that you posted this code a couple years ago, [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is now deprecated as of jQuery version 1.8, because there is a new method [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) in the AJAX section.

Note that in the line below, `displayMessage()` is called and does not return a function, so the call to `$(window).load()` appears superfluous:

> ```
> $(window).load(displayMessage(lastTimestamp));
> ```

To really make that function `displayMessage` an onload handler, one could make a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
$(window).load(displayMessage.bind(null, lastTimestamp));
```

### PHP

#### Separate endpoints

It would be wise to separate the code in the `display` function into two different endpoints - one for fetching messages (which should perhaps use the `GET` HTTP verb), and one for creating a new post (which can stay as a `POST` or a `PUT` request). That way `display` isn't concerned with creating messages, so as to adhere to the [Separation of Concerns](http://deviq.com/separation-of-concerns/) principle.

#### Laravel code?

It looks like some of the Laravel `DB` facade and Eloquent methods (e.g. `findAll()`) are used, which makes me believe this is a Laravel controller method. If that is the case, it would be wise to access POST data via the [Request object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests). Then lines like

> ```
> $text = DB::Escape($_POST['text']);
> ```

Can be updated to use the [`Request::input()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_input) method:

```
$text = DB::Escape($request->input('text'));
```

Or using the [dynamic input style](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input):

```
$text = DB::Escape($request->text);
```